# Indoor location mapping for AR ANDROID

Tags: android, location, augmented-reality, android-sensors, indoor-positioning-system

I want to identify the distance walked in certain directions.
whats the accuracy i would get?

what are the possible ways to do indoor location mapping and directions?
is there any sensors that could detect movements with More accuracy.

How to identify ground plane?
without ARCORE or tango.

Answer (score 0):

To identify ground place you will have to do spatial mapping. Either you will have to implement it your self or search for some API that do this. For indoor mapping and directions there is something called as Simultaneous Localization and Mapping (SLAM) that uses on boar sensors like gyro, accelerometer, camera, and tries to get the relative position of the user. To implement this yourself is really hard its big task and very actively researched . Search for any tools or API that provide SLAM . I am assuming you could not use GPS as you need more accurate distance traveled.